# use api token as environment variable

Tags: postman

I created a new enviroment with a variable called api-key.  I then went into the top folder of my collections under the authorizations tab, I selected the method "api key" I set my key name and on the value I set it to "{{api-key}}" which is the same name I gave the enviroment variable.  I also made sure the collection is using the correct enviroment variable.  On my GET request I see the header is greyed out with "api-key" but has no value.  If I enter a manual value, I do see it populate in the field correctly.  How can I populate that value automatically?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi make sure the collection is saved . THen only the folder level or collection level variables get parsed to the child requests :

make sure in the collection or folder , this orange icon is not there :

[image]

ALso hover over the key and see if the value is being resolved from correct scope